# Positioning rotated square

Tags: javascript, css, responsive, positioning

I need to position the three squares [Pythagoras' Theorem picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I87ke.png) to create a right angle triangle in the middle and need them to stay in this arrangement at all times resizing browser) without overlapping or moving apart. Right now I am using position:fixed for each square and placing them using percentages.

Is there a better way to do this? 
Thanks

For the 5x5 squares im using

```
#five div {
position:relative;
height: 54px;
width: 54px;
border: 1px dashed gray;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0;
}

#five {
width:300px;
height:300px;
background:yellow;
border:5px solid yellow;
margin:auto;
transform: rotate(30deg);
padding: 5px;
position: fixed;
top:20%;
left: 50%;
}
```

3x3 dark blue square

```
#three {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
border: 5px solid blue;
padding: 5px;
position: fixed;
top:48%;
left: 33%;
}
```

4x4 lightblue square

```
#four {
width: 260px;
height: 260px;
border: 5px solid lightblue;
margin-top: 5px;
padding: 5px;
position: fixed;
top:69%;
left: 45%;
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be advised, that this is not a homework production site. It is expected to tell what you have already tried, and in how far it didn't work, then ask a detailed question. Just dumping your questionnaire and asking others to fill it out for you is considered rude.

Comment: Im sorry the formatting of my message got messed up when I posted, did not mean to come off as rude.

Answer (score 0):

`position:fixed` is relative to the browser window. So if you use a percentage and modify your window size you'll get odd results.

`position: absolute` is relative to the next parent element with a specified positioning (by default the `<body>`).

Consider making a parent element set to `position: relative` and absolutely positioning your items inside of that using either percent or fixed units.

The rotation can be accomplished with a CSS transform like the [rotate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate) function.